# Atlassian Suite for non-paying customers

Tags: jira, confluence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

We're starting to roll out our product with some supporting services (wiki, bugtracker, the likes). I'm really happy so far with the Atlassian suite for these things. However, for a product which is free to download, the prices per user are way to high to give every (potential) customer a user into the system.

I was planning on making the Confluence instance public (as it's documentation is mostly not-to-edit anyways) and maybe using the JIRA wit anonymous users. Are there any major drawbacks for this? Or would you recommend another approach?

Answer (score 2):

Good question, a commonly encountered problem - I don't have an all encompassing solution readily available (for this I'd actually suggest you ask the same question in Atlassian's own Q&A site [Answers](https://answers.atlassian.com/), which sees significantly more traffic regarding their products than the Stack Exchange network, albeit both are viable approaches of course).

However, I want to bring the recently released [JIRA Issue Collector](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.collector.plugin.jira-issue-collector-plugin) plugin to your attention, which addresses this use case specifically:

> The issue collector plugin makes creating issues easy.  If you are
>   developing a web-application and want your users to raise bugs in JIRA
>   the issue collector will make this a very painless process.
>
> Instead of having to navigate to JIRA to raise bugs users will be able
>   to raise issues directly from within your web-application!
>
> [...]
>
> Users will then see a trigger they can click to raise bugs and will
>   get a form directly in your webapp to provide more details.  **They can
>   do so anonymously** or if they are already logged in in the JIRA
>   instance where the feedback will be created than their login
>   credentials can be used. *[emphasis mine]*

See [Easy issue creation for external reporters: the JIRA Issue Collector plugin beta](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2011/09/easy_issue_creation_external_reporters_jira_issue_collector/)  for an illustrated introduction of this plugin's functionality.

In addition you might want to check Andy Brook's answer to the related question [JIRA User License Count - need user license for all our end users?](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/17404/jira-user-license-count-need-user-license-for-all-our-end-users/17541), which suggests to use the JIRA email interface to create non interactive users eventually; be advised though, that the latter isn't yet available for Atlassian's new [OnDemand](http://www.atlassian.com/ondemand) platform, causing much grieve amongst existing customers accordingly, see [Support issue creation from email on the OnDemand platform (JST-5649)](https://studio.atlassian.com/browse/JST-5649?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel).

Good luck!